# Add function docstrings with Documenter.jl

Tags: julia, documentation-generation

I'm trying to create a documentation for a Julia package using `Documenter.jl`. (I'm fairly new to Julia in general though.) Now I was wondering how I can get all functions with a docstring appear in the documentation? I know I can add a function `f` via

````
## Functions

```@docs
f
```
````

in the markdown file but that would mean I have to add all functions manually. Isn't there a way of adding all functions automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok for anyone interested I just found out how to do it:

````
```@autodocs
Modules = [Foo, Bar]
Order   = [:function, :type]
```
````

as shown in https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/syntax/#@docs-block.